# 範囲指定をして置換する方法について

Tags: python

以下のデータの宛先ポート番号を50-55、56-60といったようにレンジでグループ化し、元データを置換したい。

```
csv_data = '''
送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート番号
1.1.1.1,3.3.3.3,53
1.1.1.2,3.3.3.3,57
2.2.2.2,9.9.9.9,54
2.2.2.3,9.9.9.9,59
4.4.4.4,10.10.10.10,56
20.20.20.20,30.30.30.30,60
'''
```

期待する出力結果

```
output = '''
送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート番号
1.1.1.1,3.3.3.3,50-55
1.1.1.2,3.3.3.3,56-60
2.2.2.2,9.9.9.9,50-55
2.2.2.3,9.9.9.9,56-60
4.4.4.4,10.10.10.10,56-60
20.20.20.20,30.30.30.30,56-60
'''
```

#### これまでに試したこと

以下のコードを実行しましたが、全ての宛先ポート番号が56−60のレンジになってしまいました。

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

df["宛先ポート番号"]=df["宛先ポート番号"].astype(str)
df["宛先ポート番号"]=df.loc[(df["宛先ポート番号"]>="50") & (df["宛先ポート番号"]<="55"),"宛先ポート番号”]="50-55"
df["宛先ポート番号"]=df.loc[(df["宛先ポート番号"]>="56") & (df["宛先ポート番号"]<="60"),"宛先ポート番号”]="56-60"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.cut — pandas 2.0.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) を使います。

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート番号
1.1.1.1,3.3.3.3,53
1.1.1.2,3.3.3.3,57
2.2.2.2,9.9.9.9,54
2.2.2.3,9.9.9.9,59
4.4.4.4,10.10.10.10,56
20.20.20.20,30.30.30.30,60
20.20.20.20,30.30.30.30,80
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
idx = df['宛先ポート番号'].between(50, 60)
df.loc[idx, '宛先ポート番号'] = pd.cut(df.loc[idx, '宛先ポート番号'],
                                       [50, 55, 60], labels=['50-55', '56-60'])
print(df)

#       送信元IP       宛先IP 宛先ポート番号
# 0      1.1.1.1      3.3.3.3          50-55
# 1      1.1.1.2      3.3.3.3          56-60
# 2      2.2.2.2      9.9.9.9          50-55
# 3      2.2.2.3      9.9.9.9          56-60
# 4      4.4.4.4  10.10.10.10          56-60
# 5  20.20.20.20  30.30.30.30          56-60
# 6  20.20.20.20  30.30.30.30             80
```

Comment: “<”not supported between instances of float and strのエラーが出て置換できませんでした。

Comment: 変更前の「宛先ポート番号」列の型が str 型になっているのだと思います。

Comment: df[“宛先ポート”]=df[“宛先ポート”].astype(int)を実施し、再度コマンドを実施しましたが、同様のエラーが出力されました。データ自体がおかしいかもしれません。

Comment: そうなりますと、宛先ポート列に数字以外の文字が混入している可能性が高いと思われます。

Comment: データを再度見ましたが、数値以外のものは含まれておらず、間違いはないと思います。ただ、先のコマンドを再度実行したら、宛先ポートの列がNaNになって結果が表示されました

Comment: 宛先ポートの列がNaNになるのであれば、宛先ポートが 50~60 の範囲外の整数値になっているということになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。範囲外の値については、元データの値を残したいのですが、元の値残す方法はありますでしょうか。質問ばかりですみません。